Inconsistent unresolved symbols in math and stdlib in Visual Studio
Building a C/C++ DLL in Visual Studio 2022 converted from a VS 2005 project from years ago that was in production for many years).   The linker is complaining on a handful of math and stdlib calls as if they are missing.  Strangely, the linker errors listed are a small fraction of all the math and other stdlib calls made (so most are resolved -- yet some aren't?)  See below image.  For example, fmaxf is used many places and files yet only one invocation in a particular file has a problem!?   Also, there are other symbols that I'm not even recognizing (except_handler4_common).  Tried searching and stuck.  Win32 and x64 both yield the same linker issues.
As a multi-form indie dev I'm spread thin and would deeply appreciate help!


Appreciate the support thus far and making headway.  The __iob_func items were from a lib build from an older version of VS, so recompiling that lib resolves that.
The remaining link errors away if I statically link the MSVC runtime (vs DLL runtime).  It's as if the /MD refs don't have a small subset of stdlib symbols -- round, fmax, fmin, puts.

This issue may be caused by some incompatibility or configuration issues introduced during the project. You can try the analysis and methods in the following documents to handle specific errors:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=msvc-170
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1120?view=msvc-170
